# Global pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, scheme, interpreter

I am new to C and I am currently implementing a Scheme interpreter in C. I am close to the end but a problem is bothering me which I have not been able to tackle yet.

I want a "globalEnvironment" pointer to a struct which stays throughout the time the program runs and gets modified too (not a constant).

```
/****************************************************************
 Creates the List as a pointer to the conscell structure
 */
typedef struct conscell *List;

/****************************************************************
 Creates a conscell structure, with a char pointer (symbol) and two pointers to
 * conscells (first and rest)
 */
struct conscell {
    char *symbol;
    struct conscell *first;
    struct conscell *rest;

};


List globalEnvironment;


/****************************************************************
 Function: globalVariables()
 --------------------
 This function initializes the global variables
 */
void globalVariables() {

globalEnvironment = malloc(sizeof (struct conscell));
globalEnvironment->symbol = NULL;
globalEnvironment->first = NULL;
globalEnvironment->rest = NULL;

}
```

As you can see "List" is a pointer to a conscell structure. So all I want is the globalEnvironment List to be global.

The problem is that I cannot do malloc there. If I try the following:

```
List globalEnvironment = malloc(sizeof (struct conscell));
```

instead of just "List globalEnvironment;" it gives an error that "initialiser element is not a constant"

To tackle this situation, I created a new function "globalVariables" which runs at the beginning of the program, initialises globalEnvironment and allocates it memory.
It is not working as I expected though and I keep getting segmentation fault errors for other functions that I have not written here to keep it simple.

Is there another, simpler, way to declare a pointer (not constant) to a structure in C?

Hope someone can help,
Thank you

Comment: It should work this way, maybe you should paste one of the places where you get the segfault after all.

Comment: For this specific case I'm not sure its worth the trouble, as there is nothing in that struct that mandates heap allocation (that I see anyway). I'd skip the pointer and just declare a global struct.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13785267/452307) explains why the first try doesnt work.

Comment: @WhozCraig What do you mean by declaring a global struct?

Comment: @AlokSave Thanks but I am still confused as that example is a very simple one

Comment: I mean `struct conscell globalEnvironment = {0};`. Is there some specific reason *that* variable has to be a pointer?

Comment: YES. It has to be a pointer to conscell struct. 
If I use 'struct conscell globalEnvironment = {0};' wouldn't it be just a struct and not a pointer to conscell? Or would it be a pointer to conscell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to `malloc` when you should just use global data. You could try

```
struct conscell globalEnvironment;
```

Just remember to never `free` it.

If you need to have a pointer handle so you can push cells on the list:

```
struct conscell _globalEnvironment;
List globalEnvironment = &_globalEnvironment;
```

Still, remember to never `free` `_globalEnvironment`.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` is a function and call to any function (done at run time ) so it must be inside the `main()` or some other function definition.

Also global variables must have initializer list must be a constant expression.

```
ISO :c99 , 6.5.2.5 Compound literals : paragraph 3rd of constraints,
```

3
`If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the initializer list shall
consist of constant expressions.`

Hence you are getting that error when you call `malloc()` for the `List` pointer outside any function body.

Comment: my globalVariables() function is declared in the main() but it still doesn't help
Moreover, can I still initialise it as "const" even though I know it will be modified throughout the program?

Comment: what do you mean by declaration here ? because one problem still persists if you define one function inside the other.There is no rule to define the function inside the other function. Declaration in main() is fine but definition must be outside of any function body.

Comment: by declaration I mean it is "called" in the main() function. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RehanRasool : calling from a function is fine but as I said definition should be present outside of any function.using const also not a good practice when you are going to modify it later. I think there may be some other problem . because initializing a pointer inside a function is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking this is some sort of linked list or similar dynamic ADT, and that's why you want to use malloc.

This is how you implement this functionality with proper, object-oriented program design:

conscell.h

```
/****************************************************************
 Creates a conscell structure, with a char pointer (symbol) and two pointers to
 * conscells (first and rest)
 */
typedef struct conscell {
    char *symbol;
    struct conscell *first;
    struct conscell *rest;
} conscell_t;


void conscell_init (void);
void conscell_cleanup (void);
void conscell_add (something); // function that accesses the object
```

conscell.c

```
#include "conscell.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

static conscell_t* environment;


void conscell_init() 
{
  environment = malloc(sizeof (conscell_t));

  if(environment == NULL)
  {
    // error handling
  }

  environment->symbol = NULL;
  environment->first  = NULL;
  environment->rest   = NULL;
}

void conscell_cleanup (void)
{
  // perform all custom freeing of dynamic memory here

  free(environment);
  environment = NULL;
}

void conscell_add (something)
{
  // do something with "environment" here.
}
```