# Code doesn't compile: error C2099: initializer is not a constant

Tags: c

I'm trying to get software originally written in C to compile in Visual C++. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include "timer.h"

FILE * timerFP = stdout;

int timerCount = 0;

double time_Master = 0.0;
static tsc_type tsc_Master;

void Timer_Start(void)
{
    readTSC(tsc_Master);
}

void Timer_Stop(void)
{
    tsc_type tsc_Master2;
    readTSC(tsc_Master2);
    time_Master += diffTSC(tsc_Master,tsc_Master2);
}
```

But Visual C++ gives me the following error:

```
error C2099: initializer is not a constant.
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: What is the full error message (including line number and similar) being pointed to?

Comment: Pretty sure it's this line: `FILE * timerFP = stdout;`

Comment: It points to the 'FILE * timerFP = stdout;' line

Comment: Changed the tag from [C++] to [C]. The code works as is in [C++], even if it is not valid [C]

Comment: The variable timerFP is not used, so you could eliminate that line.  stdout is not set until run time, so its' content is not know until run time.

Comment: what are the contents of timer.h and what library should be referenced in the link command?

Comment: It used to be the case that `<stdio.h>` headers on Unix-like systems would use `#define stdout __iob[0]`, which is a compile-time constant, so it used to be common practice to pre-initialize file scope (global or static) `FILE *` variables to the standard I/O streams. However, the C standard does not mandate that `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` be compile-time constants. I spotted that GNU/Linux had changed this in June 1999; it probably happened anything up to about a year earlier. There was no point in fighting a technically legitimate change; code had to be adapted to work under the new regime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can't initialize a global variable with a non-constant value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785250/definition-of-global-variables-using-a-non-constant-initializer) such as `stdout`. You need to do so inside your `main` function instead (or whatever initialization function is appropriate for your purposes):

```
FILE *timerFP;

int main(void) {
    timerFP = stdout;
    /* ... */
}
```

Alternatively, you can define it as a function:

```
FILE *timerFP(void) {
    return stdout;
}
```

A typical compiler can quite easily optimize the function call away.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have already indicated, `stdout` is not required to be a constant. For example, in MSVC++ 2013 it is defined like this on line 150 of `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdio.h`:

```
#define stdout (&__iob_func()[1])
```

which means it involves a function call. Initializers need to be compile-time constants, and `stdout` is not.

(Note that this changes between different versions of MSVC++, so your version may be different)