# Visual Studio C program run fails with VS compiler but works with Clang

Tags: c, visual-studio, clang, visual-studio-2019

Configuration: Win10 64-bit, VS2019 with all updates and Clang v12.0 installed, and a breakpoint set on the null statement.

If compile with the VS compiler, the first version of the code below hits the breakpoint after Foo is output to the console the first time, but loops as expected if compiled with Clang.  The second version loops as expected with both the VS compiler and Clang.  If I remove the breakpoint both versions loop as expected with both compilers.  Why does a breakpoint cause the first version to fail with the VS compiler?

Version 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   for (;;)
      if (fwrite("Foo", 3, 1, stdout) != 1)
         ;
}
```

Version 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   for (;;)
   {
      if (fwrite("Foo", 3, 1, stdout) != 1)
         ;
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's because [`stdout` in MSVC isn't a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27576905/995714). But I don't see how the braces are related here, probably some bug

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fail"? Does the actual output of the program differ from the expected output?

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m -
 By "fail" I mean that program flow should never reach the null statement if fwrite returns a 1 like the language standard says it should if it writes 1 object.  I suppose this may be due to some sort of optimization that the MS compiler performs.

Comment: The C language rules do not cover "program flow", whatever that means. They only define what output a program should have. Stopping or not stopping on a breakpoint is not a failure. There is no guarantee that you can put a breakpoint on a statement that has no actual machine instructions.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m - I've always considered "program flow" to be just another way of saying "flow of control" or "control flow", which are terms used freely in the C and C++ standards.   Am I off base on this?

Comment: Control flow is not observable behaviour. It is used to describe the C abstract machine, but your implementation need not behave the exact same way, only the observable behaviour should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the actual issue is hitting breakpoint on empty statement, where `if` condition is evaluated to false.

It is not a "fail": the observed program behavior is the same, and compiler may emit whatever instructions to match the observed behavior. The more optimizations are enabled, the more compiler would "transform" the program.

There's a workaround to insert `__nop()` intrinsic. The compiler will emit one-byte purpose-less instruction, but it will not omit it, and will make control flow fair. This is the most lightweight way to have something that compiler won't optimize away.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (;;)
        if (fwrite("Foo", 3, 1, stdout) != 1)
            __nop();
}
```

Note that adding this intrinsic into a program may make the code slightly less optimal, and it would be mostly caused not by extra instruction, but by limiting the compiler in transforming program. For your case, compiler is very likely to throw away the whole `!= 1` comparison, but it won't do that with `__nop()`.

Comment: Yes, that does solve the problem in this case.  However, the simplified examples I used came from more complex code that called a function that displayed an error message and exited the program if fwrite did not return 1.  If I can I'll try to recreate it in a more simplified fashion and update my posting.